# Bad Minute error Crontab

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I am pretty new to crontab so this may be a pretty obvious syntax error, but I can't figure out what the problem is. I've looked at a lot of other posts with the same problem but I can't narrow down the issue.

```
PYTHONPATH =/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
MAILTO="email@email.com"
45 13 * * * chmod +x  /home/elalo/ServiceNow/scheduler.py >/tmp/out.txt 2>&1
touch /tmp/out.txt
tail /tmp/out.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"this may be a pretty obvious syntax error"_ What may? I don't see any error quoted in full in your post. Can you add that?

Comment: The title of this post is "Bad minute error", that's the error.

Comment: I'd assumed the program would've given a more descriptive error, or a line number, or something, but OK.

Comment: You have got a space between `PYTHONPATH` and `=`: typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were actually a few reasons why this was not working.

The out files were messing with it and I did not need to include the `chmod a+x`
I also did not have the python path correctly laid out.

the correct ways is denote the python path:

```
/usr/bin/python3.4
```

then add the path to the script so in total it looks likes

```
MAILTO="email@address"
30 12 * * * /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/elalo/ServiceNow/scheduler.py
```

Also, inside of the script, I referenced files in the same directory and those also needed the full path.

For example:

```
scheduler.txt
```

Needed to be

```
/home/elalo/ServiceNow/scheduler.txt
```